# Парсинг ссылок в таблице?

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, парсер

Есть html страница

```
<table class="Tab_AddTovar7">
<tr>
            <th><div class="col_tab_1">Вид металла</div></th>
            <th><div class="TR_AddTovar_head7">Диаметр</div></th>
            <th class="col_tab_1"><div class="TR_AddTovar_head7">Длина</div></th>
            <th class="col_tab_1"><div class="TR_AddTovar_head7">ГОСТ, ОСТ, ТУ</div></th>
            <th><div class="TR_AddTovar_head7">Марка</div></th>
            <th><div class="TR_AddTovar_head7">Цена</div></th>
        <th><div class="TR_AddTovar_head7">Купить</div></th>
                </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><a class="col_tab_1" href="/product/tovar01">Цис</a></td>
                    <td>
                            <a class="link_tab7">18,0</a>
                    </td>
                    <td class="col_tab_1">
                            <a class="link_tab7">18,0</a>
                    </td>
                    <td class="col_tab_1"> 
                        <a class="link_tab7" href="/gost/28/19/99/2276"><strong>ТУ 14-176-122-94</strong></a>
                    </td>
                    <td >
```

Нужна ссылка /product/tovar01

Делаю так:

```
for tovar in bf.cssselect('.Tab_AddTovar7 td a'):
    ba = tovar.cssselect('a')[0]
    bhref = ba.get('href')
```

Но в результате парсятся те ссылки которые не нужны, как сделать что бы парсилась только моя ссылка?

Comment: а откуда взялся "divAddTovar7"? его в приведенном html нет

Comment: @gil9red исправил

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пример получения ссылок внутри тега с `class="Tab_AddTovar7"`:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

text = '''
<table class="Tab_AddTovar7">
<tr>
            <th><div class="col_tab_1">Вид металла</div></th>
            <th><div class="TR_AddTovar_head7">Диаметр</div></th>
            <th class="col_tab_1"><div class="TR_AddTovar_head7">Длина</div></th>
            <th class="col_tab_1"><div class="TR_AddTovar_head7">ГОСТ, ОСТ, ТУ</div></th>
            <th><div class="TR_AddTovar_head7">Марка</div></th>
            <th><div class="TR_AddTovar_head7">Цена</div></th>
        <th><div class="TR_AddTovar_head7">Купить</div></th>
                </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><a class="col_tab_1" href="/product/tovar01">Цис</a></td>
                    <td>
                            <a class="link_tab7">18,0</a>
                    </td>
                    <td class="col_tab_1">
                            <a class="link_tab7">18,0</a>
                    </td>
                    <td class="col_tab_1"> 
                        <a class="link_tab7" href="/gost/28/19/99/2276"><strong>ТУ 14-176-122-94</strong></a>
                    </td>
                    <td >
            </tr>
</table>
'''

root = BeautifulSoup(text, 'html.parser')
print(root.select_one('.Tab_AddTovar7 a.col_tab_1')['href'])  # /product/tovar01
```

Можно сделать фильтрацию по всем ссылкам, например:

```
links = [a['href'] for a in root.select('.Tab_AddTovar7 a[href]')]
print(links)  # ['/product/tovar01', '/gost/28/19/99/2276']

links = [a['href'] for a in root.select('.Tab_AddTovar7 a[href]') if a['href'].startswith('/product')]
print(links)  # ['/product/tovar01']
```

Comment: через lxml можно? (bs4 не хочется использовать)

Comment: Можно. Просто перепишите код на lxml

Comment: @gli9red спасибо
for tovar in bf.cssselect('.divAddTovar7 a.col_tab_1'):

Comment: Хорошо выглядит, вы молодец :)